# freopen_s("conout$") and fclose

Tags: c++, c, windows, freopen

Visual C++ is reporting that an invalid parameter was passed to `fclose`, that parameter being the `FILE*` returned by freopen_s:

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <iostream>

int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(nCmdShow);

#ifdef _DEBUG
    AllocConsole();
#else
    AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
#endif

    FILE* pCout;
    freopen_s(&pCout, "conout$", "w", stdout); //returns 0

    fclose(pCout);

#ifdef _DEBUG
    system("pause");
#endif

    FreeConsole();

    return 0;
}
```

Should I not attempt to close conout$ at the end of the program?  Is the exception being thrown because the file pointer is shared between processes for all console output?

Comment: No repro with Visual C++ 2013.  Please provide a complete repro that demonstrates the problem.  What does the call to `freopen_s` return?  (If you're going to call the `_s`-variant, you need to check the returned status.)

Comment: The errno_t returned is 0, which means no error, right?

Comment: This only happens in release mode, by the way, even though the function returns 0 in both cases.

Comment: Given the results @JamesMcNellis reports, you need to post working code to demo the problem.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis I commented out all code between freopen_s and fclose and there's no difference, so it's just those functions that are causing the problem.

Comment: No repro with VS 2010 either.  Your problem lies elsewhere.  It's probably files you're including, compiler options, or something else you're not showing us.  The code as-is works fine.

Comment: Wow, small number of lines of code added but huge change.  I had assumed a console app.

Comment: With your new code `freopen_s` is failing, so it's not surprising that `fclose` is failing.  You're building the app as a Windows app but using functions that assume a console app.  I think that's where your problem lies.

Comment: @CareyGregory Then what do I use to open stdout?  std::wcout doesn't work otherwise.

Comment: "This only happens in release mode, by the way."  You call `AllocConsole()` for debug builds but not for release builds.  Therein lies the difference.  If there's no console then when the CRT calls `CreateFile()` to open `conout$`, the call will fail.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis What about AttachConsole?

Comment: If the parent process doesn't have a console, the call to `AttachConsole()` fails, as is explained in the documentation.

Comment: Also, note that when the call to `freopen_s` fails, it _does not_ return zero like you said:  it returns `EBADF`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call to `fclose` is failing because you are passing a null `FILE*`.  The `FILE*` is null because the call to `freopen_s` fails.  That call fails because the process has no console to be opened.

Your program works in debug builds because you call `AllocConsole` to allocate a console for your process.  Your program does not work in release builds because you do not call `AllocConsole`; you call `AttachConsole`, which will fail (and have no effect) if the parent process has no console.

Comment: +1 for nicely summarizing all the comments and my answer into one cohesive answer.  I made the mistake of continuing comments into an answer.

Comment: Okay, whoops.  This should have been obvious from the beginning, but I was checking output from the command prompt, where AllocConsole and freopen_s weren't failing, and debugging from VS with no console, where AllocConsole and freopen_s were failing.  The debugger still reported the return value of freopen_s as 0, though, so maybe it was just inaccurate.